# Grouping daily data by month in python/pandas while firstly grouping by user id

Tags: python, pandas

I have the table below in a Pandas dataframe:

```
date                 user_id  whole_cost  cost1             
02/10/2012 00:00:00        1       1790      12         
07/10/2012 00:00:00        1        364      15         
30/01/2013 00:00:00        1        280      10         
02/02/2013 00:00:00        1        259      24         
05/03/2013 00:00:00        1        201      39         
02/10/2012 00:00:00        3        623       1          
07/12/2012 00:00:00        3         90       0          
30/01/2013 00:00:00        3        312      90         
02/02/2013 00:00:00        5        359      45         
05/03/2013 00:00:00        5        301      34         
02/02/2013 00:00:00        5        359       1          
05/03/2013 00:00:00        5        801      12         
..
```

The table was extracted from a csv file using the following query :

```
import pandas as pd

newnames = ['date','user_id', 'whole_cost', 'cost1']
df = pd.read_csv('expenses.csv', names = newnames, index_col = 'date')
```

I have to analyse the profile of my users and for this purpose:

I would like to group (for each user - they are thousands) queries by month summing the query `whole_cost` for the entire month e.g. if `user_id=1` was has a whole cost of 1790 on 02/10/2012 with cost1 12 and on the 07/10/2012 with whole cost 364, then it should have an entry in the new table of 2154 (as the whole cost) on 31/10/2012 (end of the month end-point representing the month - all dates in the transformed table will be month ends representing the whole month to which they relate).

Answer (score 9):

In 0.14 you'll be able to groupby monthly and another column at the same time:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
            user_id  whole_cost  cost1
2012-10-02        1        1790     12
2012-10-07        1         364     15
2013-01-30        1         280     10
2013-02-02        1         259     24
2013-03-05        1         201     39
2012-10-02        3         623      1
2012-12-07        3          90      0
2013-01-30        3         312     90
2013-02-02        5         359     45
2013-03-05        5         301     34
2013-02-02        5         359      1
2013-03-05        5         801     12

In [12]: df1 = df.sort_index()  # requires sorted DatetimeIndex

In [13]: df1.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'), 'user_id'])['whole_cost'].sum()
Out[13]:
            user_id
2012-10-31  1          2154
            3           623
2012-12-31  3            90
2013-01-31  1           280
            3           312
2013-02-28  1           259
            5           718
2013-03-31  1           201
            5          1102
Name: whole_cost, dtype: int64
```

until 0.14 I think you're stuck with doing two groupbys:

```
In [14]: g = df.groupby('user_id')['whole_cost']

In [15]: g.resample('M', how='sum').dropna()
Out[15]:
user_id
1        2012-10-31    2154
         2013-01-31     280
         2013-02-28     259
         2013-03-31     201
3        2012-10-31     623
         2012-12-31      90
         2013-01-31     312
5        2013-02-28     718
         2013-03-31    1102
dtype: float64
```

Comment: hmm. I don't think the sorting is required in 0.14 (pretty sure I fixed that).

Comment: Hi, I am a bit confused : does your variable 'df' corresponds to my variable 'frame'? If yes, then the type of df is DataFrame instead of DatetimeIndex (I previously had a message error due to this). How can I convert 'frame' to DatetimeIndex (I loaded datas from a .csv file)?

Comment: @jeff maybe I've not updated pandas on this machine. Will have a check (the above example was different / broken without sorting) - I think it's still mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @user3102882 df is a DataFrame. You want the date index to be a datetime index (do this with `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=True`, or when reading in the csv)

Comment: @AndyHayden When I use df1.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'), 'user_id'])['whole_cost'].sum() I receive the error message 'Time grouper object is not callable'

Comment: @user3102882 as I say, that will be available in 0.14. Until then use the second command.

Comment: @AndyHayden Using the second command I receive the error message : 'Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex' after g.resample('M', how='sum').dropna()

Comment: @user3102882 you have to ensure that the index is a DatetimeIndex. Did you follow the instruction above? `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=True)`

Comment: @AndyHayden I use this last statement and it is works fine now.However, can you please explain why there is no difference between g.resample('M', how='sum') and g.resample('M', how='mean')  (I am trying to obtain average monthly value instead of sum of monthly per month)?

Comment: @AndyHayden I just forgot since I resolved the issue while working on another one.

Comment: Sorry, but in fact it still not working : I used pivot table instead of this method but presently I still need to resolve the above issue.Because there is now an additional column with dates all at 1970-01-01.

Comment: @user3102882 you should ask a new question if the situation has changed.

Comment: When I try your code above, the dates remain not ordered.

Comment: @user3102882 you're looking for `df.sort_index()`. Like I say this is really a different issue.

Comment: For the same date I have more than one entry for the same user id and I believe that is where the issue come from. Can't I use something another method not using a dataframe?

Comment: @user3102882 you should post a new question with the specific instance where this fails. Having duplicates should not be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

With timegrouper getting deprecated, you can replace it with Grouper to get the same results

```
df.groupby(['user_id', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')]).agg({'whole_cost':sum})

df.groupby(['user_id', df['date'].dt.dayofweek]).agg({'whole_cost':sum})
```